# Android logcat - none reference to imported library

Tags: android, android-studio, android-logcat

I'm working on Android Studio. I've imported a library using this code to avoid to copy the library files in app project:

setting.gradle:

```
include ':app', ':mylibrary'
project(':mylibrary').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../MyLibrary/app')
```

build.gradle (app):

```
dependencies {
    compile project(path: ':mylibrary')
}
```

The build is ok but in logcat I have no reference to library class if there's some error. I receive a log like this without the line of the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.dimapp.wsmc.MainActivity.a(Unknown Source)
```

How can I solve? Without the line of the error the debug is almost impossible.

Thanks,

Simone

**EDIT**

I try to explain better:

In the Activity of my library I've created a classic NullPointerException at **row 270**:

```
ActionBar actionBar = null; //getSupportActionBar(); 
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

In my logcat I have:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
           at com.dimapp.wsmc.MainActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
```

while I should have:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
           at com.dimapp.wsmc.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:270)
```

Comment: `at com.dimapp.wsmc.MainActivity.a` means that the error is in method `a()` of `com.dimapp.wsmc.MainActivity`

Comment: Post your MainActivity code

Comment: The method name `a` seems something like obfuscated by ProGuard.

Comment: @Angela the problem is not a specific error but that in logcat, if the error is in a external library, I haven't the row of the error but a generic "Unknown Source". Then I'm not able to understand where is the error and I can't fix it (MainActivity has more then 1300 rows)

Comment: @hata ProGuard is used only in release build, Now I'm working on debug build.